# Big headache with SQL syntax - need help - page doesn't send new row to server

Tags: sql

I am currently learning sql but I cannot get some things done like send a new data to the localhost when I am submiting data

```
$short_title=$_POST['short_title'];
$title=$_POST['title']; 
$statement=$connection->prepare(
  'INSERT INTO post (title,short_name) VALUES (:title,:short_name)');
$statement->execute(array(':title'=>$title,':short_name'=>$short_title));
```

Comment: What platform is this? PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the db_connect file please?

And is the ID of the table in Auto-Increment?

Something seems wrong with your last line. Are you using PDO or MYSQLI?

Here is an example of a query and a db_connect file in PHP using PDO method

The db connect :

```
<?php
    $db_username = "root";
    $db_password = "";
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_name = "veterinaires";

    $db_options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");

        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name};charset=utf8", $db_username, $db_password, $db_options);
        } catch(PDOException $ex) {
            die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Model for insert in DB

```
<?php
    /* Basic function */
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (
            ID,
            password,
            email,
            role
        ) VALUES (
            :ID,
            :password,
            :email,
            :role)";
        // Security measures
    $query_params = array(
        ':ID' => NULL,
        ':password' => $password,
        ':email' => $email,
        ':role' => 'vet');
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        $check = true;
    }catch(PDOException $ex){   
        $errormsg = "Vous possédez déjà un compte!";
        $check = false;
    }
?>
```

Comment: yes is Auto-Increment on primary key (''id")  $connection=connection('localhost','root','');   YEAH IS PDO

Comment: Oh, and set a "var_dump($_POST); " before you reach the query, so you're sure you get the datas you need

Comment: Can you put all the files you're using for this specific feature?